# How to edit the data in a Gridcontrol and save it in a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I use SQL Server as my project backend. I have a DataGrid that gets filled with data from the database. I need to add new items in the grid while the app is running; the new data should get saved back in the database. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried with google?.. or please post your code.. so that we can easily find out where problem is occured. no one can provide complete set of code.

Comment: Is it a windows application or web application?

Answer (score 0):

Your grid is most probably binded to your sql datasource, so you can just open that form in designer. Click on that icon in top right corner of grid (icon for customizing the grid), and there you should be able to select a option, that allows adding grid items.

Comment: thanks for the informatiom Dampe..But what i have to do when am using Gridcontrol?

Comment: You said you are using 'DataGrid` which I understood as a `DataGridView` in toolbox and this is the control that behaves as I described. I do not know what are you refering to, if not DataGridView.

Comment: Ah, ok then nevermind. I haven't worked with that one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some projects using Visual Basic as Front end & SQL as Backend...
in which i have used Grids for displaying the backend data in the front end form.. 
Do u want a code of that  or u just want to know how to add the new items?
you can just open an option in the Data grid to add new items in it as suggested by Dampe.